# Creating link between sent and received message

Tags: .net, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to create a link between sent message and response received against that message. According to my research, the response on sms sent and received contains 3 sids.

1. account_sid.
2. sid
3. message_service_sid

But according to twilio all of the above will be unique on each request. So using sid will not going to solve this issue.

Is there any other way to achieve the above? any help/guidance will be appreciated.

I have seen these below ids but are different on every request both on sent sms and received messages. So this is not going to solve this problem.

1. account_sid.
2. sid
3. message_service_sid

Comment: `sent message and response received against that message` Does response message contains sent message? cause other than that, only link between two is same user/account and you can use that

Comment: no it doesn't contain sent message. user account can be different because message can received from any non twilio number.

Comment: What is the service you are trying to work with? You send a message to user and they can reply with any other number? What is the reply? some kind of identification must be there which user should sent.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Twilio Cookies](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136287-How-do-Twilio-cookies-work-) to recognize a sender/receiver pair?

Comment: @IObert there are some time limit duration limit with twilio cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Your application tracks the pairing using the sender's phone number (From parameter) and receiver's phone number (To parameter). You *assume* that all messages from the sender (From) belong to the receiver (To). With this approach there is no way for the sender to have multiple un-related exchanges with the receiver. In other words, the pairing of the sender and receiver phone number is unique to a specific conversation.
2. Use [Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations) and let it keep track of all this for you: "The Conversation object is a core component of Twilio Conversations. A Conversation is a distinct message thread that contains Participant objects, which represent humans or bots who are participating in the Conversation. A Participant sends a Message, which is relayed to every other Participant in the Conversation."